# Django Template Language - getting url encoded values

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm using Django Template language, using **load staticfiles**. However when I do the following

```
<img src="{% static 'img/category/{{category.category|lower|slugify}}.jpg' %}">
```

I get the HTML as

```
<img src="/static/img/category/%7B%7Bcategory.category%7Clower%7Cslugify%7D%7D.jpg">
```

which obviously is not rendering the correct image.

However my expected output was

```
<img src="/static/img/category/electronics.jpg">
```

where `category.category = electronics`

I'm passing category as a `ctx` variable. Why is it happening like this?

Comment: Because you're trying to use tag syntax inside a tag. This is a frequent misconception, but I'm curious as to why you would think it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a variable in the `static` tag, that's why you see these `%7B%7B` in your HTML output.

You can however do this:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% get_static_prefix %}img/category/{{category.category|lower|slugify}}.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all - shouldn't that image be served from media files? Static files are not designed to be connected with models, that's what media files are for.

Secondly - you can't use variables syntax inside other tags in django. Unless tag is designed to take some parameters, you can't pass them into.