# django template turn off autoescape not working in static tag

Tags: django

I am trying to load mathjax locally in  however, the autoescape tag doesn't seem to be doing anything...

```
{% autoescape off %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'app/js/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML'|safe %}"></script>
{% endautoescape %}
```

returns

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/app/js/MathJax/MathJax.js%3Fconfig%3DTeX-MML-AM_CHTML
```

I've also tried to filter as |safe, with no success.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at the duplicate @solarissmoke, I missed it, but it solved my problem - use the get_static_prefix tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate resolving static file path and adding parameters:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'app/js/MathJax/MathJax.js' %}?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
```

Also when registering static file via media, special symbols are not encoded, for example:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):    
    class Media:
        js = (
            'app/js/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML',
        )
```

Or use `{% get_static_prefix %}` tag like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167517/django-template-language-getting-url-encoded-values).